# FMAD format in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I cannot find a document that explains the the following instruction format in CUDA

```
FMAD R6, -R6, c [0x1] [0x1], R5;
```

What is the format (source, destination, ...) and what is that `-R6`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PTX reference guide describes [fma](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#floating-point-instructions-fma) as follows

```
fma.rnd{.ftz}{.sat}.f32  d, a, b, c;
fma.rnd.f64              d, a, b, c;
```

performs

```
d = a*b + c;
```

in either single or double precision.

You are looking at disassembled SASS, the instruction set [references](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#gt200) for that show FMAD as being the (non IEEE 754 compliant) single precision form from the GT200 instruction set. That is a little bit problematic, because I don't presently have a toolchain which supports that deprecated instruction set. However, if I use the Fermi instruction set instead and compile this kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(const float *x, const float *y, float *a)
{
    float xval = x[threadIdx.x];
    float yval = y[threadIdx.x];

    float aval = -xval * xval + yval;
    a[threadIdx.x] = aval;:
}
```

I get this SASS:

```
code for sm_20
    Function : _Z6kernelPKfS0_Pf
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
    /*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                       /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
    /*0008*/         S2R R3, SR_TID.X;                            /* 0x2c0000008400dc04 */
    /*0010*/         MOV32I R5, 0x4;                              /* 0x1800000010015de2 */
    /*0018*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R8.CC, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x20];    /* 0x200b800080321c03 */
    /*0020*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R9, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x24];  /* 0x208a800090325c43 */
    /*0028*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R6.CC, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x28];    /* 0x200b8000a0319c03 */
    /*0030*/         LD.E R0, [R8];                               /* 0x8400000000801c85 */
    /*0038*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R7, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x2c];  /* 0x208a8000b031dc43 */
    /*0040*/         IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x30];    /* 0x200b8000c0311c03 */
    /*0048*/         LD.E R2, [R6];                               /* 0x8400000000609c85 */
    /*0050*/         IMAD.U32.U32.HI.X R5, R3, R5, c[0x0][0x34];  /* 0x208a8000d0315c43 */
    /*0058*/         FFMA.FTZ R0, -R0, R0, R2;                    /* 0x3004000000001e40 */
    /*0060*/         ST.E [R4], R0;                               /* 0x9400000000401c85 */
    /*0068*/         EXIT;                                        /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
    ..................................
```

Note that I also have the negated register in the `FFMA.FTZ` arguments. So I would guess that your:

```
FMAD R6, -R6, c [0x1] [0x1], R5;
```

is the equivalent of

```
R6 = -R6 * const + R5
```

where `c [0x1] [0x1]` is a compile time constant, and that the GPU has some sort of instruction modifier which it can set to control negation of a floating point value as part of a floating point operation without explicitly twiddling the sign bit of the register before the call.

(I look forward to @njuffa tearing this answer to shreds).

Comment: From memory: Various GPU machine instructions include input modifiers, in particular `-X` (negate the input) and `|X|` (take the absolute value of the input) for floating-point instructions, and `~X` (form 1's complement of the input) for integer instructions. These modifications can be applied very cheaply, and presumably aid code density (fewer instructions for the same number of operations). They also simplify the SASS instruction set, as there is only a single FMA mnemonic (while other architectures have separate mnemonics for FMA, FMS, FNMA, FNMS).

Comment: @njuffa: Thank you, I figured it must be something like that.